# Python. After using defined function i can't call for variable this function was operating on

Tags: python, function, variables, return

I wanted to write a game of ships, where player has to guess where computer "hide" ships on the board. My problem is, that everything looks fine, program compiles without an error but my predetermined functions doesn't work and I dont know why. I feel like my variable **board** gets lost after being processed by function **ship** and i can't print the board with ship on it afterwards. I tried to use **return bo** at the end of **ship** function but it doesn't work either.
What might be wrong?
I'm really lost and don't know what might be a problem here :(

```
import random
board = []

for i in range(0,10):
   board.append([0])
   for j in range(0,9):
    board[i].append(0)
def board_print(bo):
for i in range(len(bo)):
    if i == 0:
        print("--------------------")
    for j in range(len(bo[0])):
        if j == 9:
            print(bo[i][j])
        else:
            print(str(bo[i][j]) + " ", end="")
    print("--------------------")
def ship_start():
  pos_x = random.randint(0,9)
  pos_y = random.randint(0,9)
  return(pos_x,pos_y) # coordinates of ships first point
def ship(bo): # creates ship with 4 hp points
  row , col = ship_start()
  print(row, col)
  coin_flip = 1 #random.randint(0,1) # 0 - horizontal, 1 - vertical
  if coin_flip == 1:
    i = 0
    while 3 - i > 0:
       if bo[row + i][col] in bo == True:
          bo[row][col] = 1
          i =i + 1
       else:
          j = 4 - i
          for x in range(j):
            bo[row - x][col] = 1
ship(board)
board_print(board)
```

Comment: did you indent here? --> ```def board_print(bo):
for i in range(len(bo)):```

Answer (score 0):

This line is broken, in two different ways:

> ```
> if bo[row + i][col] in bo == True:
> ```

the first issue is that Python has a feature called [*chained comparisons*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

This allows creating nice math-style comparison chains e.g. `0 <= foo < 5` or `a == b == c`, but somewhat unexpectedly *the comparisons are arbitrary*, meaning you can write `a < b in c > d` and that will effectively execute as `(a < b) and (b in c) and (c > d)` (except only evaluating each expression once).

This means

```
bo[row + i][col] in bo == True
```

is not parsed as

```
(bo[row+1][col] in bo) == True
```

(which is, incidentally, redundant) but as

```
(bo[row+1][col] in bo) and (bo == True)
```

which can never be true since `bo` is not a boolean, therefore `i` is never updated and the loop never terminates.

It's not that anything is lost, it's that `ship` *literally never terminates*.

*Then* you have a second logic issue:

```
bo[row + i][col]
```

is an integer, but `bo` is a list of lists, so even without the broken comparison

```
bo[row + i][col] in bo
```

can never be true, and thus `ship` *still* can not ever terminate. I can't really help any more than that, because I've no idea what this function is actually trying to do.

There's a bunch of other minor issues / misures of the language e.g. `board_print` could largely just iterate on `bo` directly, or you could use a list comprehension and list multiplication to init your board:

```py
board = [[0] * 10 for _ in range(10)]
def board_print(bo):
    print("--------------------")
    for row in bo:
        for cell in row:
            print(cell, end=' ')
        print()
    print("--------------------")
```

And you should probably store the board size in a constant and use `randrange` in order for everything to match (`randrange(10)` is the same as `randint(0, 9)`). And `return` is not a function, conventionally there's a space between the keyword and whatever's being returned.

Comment: According first issue, should i prase it as:
     if (bo[row + i][col] in bo) == True:
Or this sentence is fundamentaly wrong and i should try something else?
Second issue. I'm, its a lost of lists but the elements in this lists are intigers, why can't i add intiger to a list element which is also an intiger?

Comment: You can add the parens but you should not: the `== True` is completely usless, you can just remove it: the value is already a boolean, and even if it were not Python's conditionals work with "truthiness" rather than require actual booleans.

Comment: For the second, the issue is that you're looking for an integer in a list of lists of integers. `in` does not "punch through", it will just look at all the values in the outer list, never find anything, and go away. Furthermore you're trying to find a board value inside the board, this would be true by definition.

Comment: I don't get this second issue. When i call for bo[row+i][col] and row and col are both intigers and i is intiger shouldnt they sum and point to specific point on board e. g. bo[5][6]?

Comment: It points to a value in the board e.g. the `0` which is at `bo[5][6]`, but then you ask `if 0 in bo`. bo is an array of arrays, not a multi-dimensional matrix, so the only thing in bo are arrays. Therefore `0` is not in `bo`, `0` can never be in `bo`.

Comment: Ok now i get it! Thank you very much for you in-depth insight into my program. Have a nice day :)